# Wordpress tinyMCE will not open window on production server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

Ok so here's the deal. Using the code below, I have created a custom button in the tinyMCE editor which opens a modal window and loads a php file I created. This is NOT a plugin for Wordpress, I've built the functionality directly into my theme.

It works perfectly on my local environment (Ubuntu running LAMP with a vhost file loading the site as wordpress.loc if any of this helps) but on my production server, running cpanel the modal window cant seem to find the php file. It 404s. So I guess the WP routing system is getting in the way.. but I'm having this issue with both the latest version of WP and tinyMCE and the last.

Here is how Im setting it up:

```
function register_button($buttons) {  
   array_push($buttons,"|" ,"kjdShortCodeInjection");  
   return $buttons;  
}  

function add_plugin($plugin_array) {  
    $admin_dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/lib/admin';
    $mce_plugin_js = $admin_dir.'/functions/shortcode-injector/mcePlugin.js';

    $plugin_array['kjdShortCodeInjection'] = $mce_plugin_js;  
    return $plugin_array;  
} 

     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin');  
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_button');
```

And the JS which I need for tinyMCE:

```
    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addCommand('mcekjdShortCodeInjection', function() {
            ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url+'/shortcode_window.php',
                title: "Select a shortcode",
                popup_css: "bootstrap.css",
                width : 900 + ed.getLang('kjdShortCodeInjection.delta_width', 0),
                height : 600 + ed.getLang('kjdShortCodeInjection.delta_height', 0),
                inline : 1
            }, {
                plugin_url : url // Plugin absolute URL
            });
        });
```

Almost every example or tutorial I've found has the button added as a plugin, and therefor is using `WP_PLUGIN_URL` or `plugins_url`

Is there a way I can get the accessible absolute path?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same .htaccess file in both installations?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the Absolute Path in `mcePlugin.js`

Add the following code in your `functions.php` file

```
add_action('admin_head','my_js_var_admin');
function my_js_var_admin() {

    if ( is_admin() ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ABSURL = '<?php echo __DIR__; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Now this is how you can user the `ABSURL` in your `mcePlugin.js` file

```
file : ABSURL+'/shortcode_window.php',  // Assign your File Path here
```

Hope this is help you.

Comment: `is_admin` is not needed as `admin_head` runs only on admin side. The check should be for the post editing page instead.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either, I still get a 404. In fact, with this method it 404's on my local machine too. I think the issue is with the wordpress routing

Comment: @rugbert Where does shortcode_window.php live in relation to your functions.php file in the theme?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of injecting variables from PHP into the scripts is this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-tinymce-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/admin.js', array('jquery'), $version);

//Inject variables into the script. The script slug(first parameter) must match the slug used in wp_enqueue_script.
wp_localize_script('my-tinymce-admin-script', 'my_vars', array(
    'theme_url' => get_template_directory_uri(),
));
```

Then you can access the variable in the script with `my_vars.theme_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Much better if you can use plugins... CF7MCE is one plugin.. . link below

http://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-mce-css/

http://ecolosites.eelv.fr/cf7mce-editeur-visuel-pour-contact-form-7/

All the while coding and adding scripts are much admirable, wordpress supports plugins, and there are many plugins that help you achieve whatever you want. Also, plugins mostly have code programmed according to professional standards (read reviews wherever available.)

It helps you with a lot of work automatically done, switching between themes is easier too. And you have a plugin for almost everything.